# Is it secure to post a Windows 7 minidump file online?

Tags: windows-7, minidumps

I realise it's unlikely that posting the file would cause a problem. However, since I know nothing about what a what's in a minidump file I thought I should check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is example of minidump http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/w/minidump.txt
Content of it is

- The Stop message, its parameters and other data
- A list of loaded drivers
- The processor context (PRCB) for the processor that stopped
- The process information and kernel context (EPROCESS) for the process
  that stopped
- The process information and kernel context (ETHREAD) for    the
  thread that stopped
- The Kernel-mode call stack for the thread that stopped

More information here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263#method1